# How to get access to enum variant unnamed field?

Tags: enums, rust

I would like to print data of tuple enum without named fields.

A tuple is a general way of grouping together some number of other values with a variety of types into one compound type.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Coin {
    Penny(String),
    Nickel { id: String },
}

fn main() {
    let penny = Coin::Penny(String::from("penny"));
    let nickel: Coin = Coin::Nickel { id: String::from("nickel") };

    println!("{} {:?} ", penny.0, penny);
    println!("{:?}", nickel);
}
```

In this example, `Nickel` is a struct-like enum variant, whereas `Penny` is simply called an [enum variant](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/enumerations.html).

I get a compiler error:

```
error[E0609]: no field `0` on type `Coin`
For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0609`.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `match` statement or alternatively an `if let` statement to use the variant's associated value:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Coin {
    Penny(String),
    Nickel { id: String },
}

fn main() {
    let penny = Coin::Penny(String::from("penny"));
    let nickel: Coin = Coin::Nickel {
        id: String::from("nickel"),
    };

    if let Coin::Penny(name) = penny {
        println!("{}", name);
    }

    if let Coin::Nickel{ id } = nickel {
        println!("{}", id);
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d4436f3aad76a2c437aa7df557a423ba&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Answer (score 5):

Example using `match` statement:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Coin {
    Penny(String),
    Nickel { id: String },
}

fn main() {
    let penny = Coin::Penny(String::from("penny"));
    let nickel: Coin = Coin::Nickel {
        id: String::from("nickel"),
    };

    match &penny {
        Coin::Penny(id) => {
            println!("{}; {:?}", id, penny);
        }
        _ => {}
    }

    match &nickel {
        Coin::Nickel { id } => {
            println!("{}; {:?}", id, nickel);
        }
        _ => {}
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=96d350af1d476a135b5d6ecf1c3de9e7&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Comment: what if the value is dynamic and we dont know which variant